# IOS- Swift-Firebase Auth token lasts after deleting the app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need an hand in solve this problem. I am simulating the case in which a user has deleted the app and removed from the authenticated users in Firebase and then reinstalled the app.

Once the app is reinstalled again the call below:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if user != nil {
            // User is signed in. Show home screen
```

return user !=nil so the user is redirected on the main VC without authentication and no right to do so.

After a couple of hours the same call reports user == nil prompting for the auth VC.

I suspect this is due to a Auth token which takes time to expire.
How to handle this situation in a clean way and be sure that if the user has no authentication on Firebase it needs to be redirected into the auth VC?

I am using phonenumber auth only if this is important.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to Firebase documentation: [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)

The registration token may change when:

- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data.

Under that logic, every time you send the firebase token to your backend and you notice user1 has changed token, you can assume he reinstalled the app, hence sending him to the view controller you see fit, now as to your problem that user eventually reports nil, that sounds like an issue on how you're saving the data, not a firebase issue in itself, are you saving the user in a database? user defaults? check your implementation.

Comment: Hi, I am doing nothing more, nothing less than https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth Only think I am saving on userdefaults is UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID") as per manual. Also I remove the user on the DB when I make this tests.

Comment: According to firebase documentation what you need to do is this review the user from firebase AFTER you've logged in, it makes perfect sense for that function to return nil after its used because the function is only used to log the user in, then in that same block returns the user, but never again after that.

What you need is to connect to Firebase auth itself, after logging in and use 

if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
  // User is signed in.
  // ...
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
  // ...
}

Docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users

Comment: Hi Velix007, thanks for that but it's definitively a no from what I see here.  Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid still reports the old uid until it expires. The only way to intercept quickly that the app was reinstalled is to mark with a userdefault and auth again if that UserDefaults is nil. This is very strange and I do not think it's by design otherwise I would expect many complains. Point is I don't know why this is happening as I don't know where the auth token from Firebase is stored. I repeat, this is happening only when the user reinstalls the app within a short period of time 1//2 hours

Comment: Question, why are you trying so hard to see if a user has uninstalled an app? There is only hacky ways to do this, as far as I know there’s no official way to check if a user has done this.

Comment: Cause I need to test some features so doing those tests I got scared on which impression a customer can have if we ask him to reinstall the app for whenever reason and it is working that weird. Bad impression, customer gone.

Comment: Why are you testing features on live users? Do your UX in the street before implementing features for input, do your QA yourself and TestFlight whoever you can to help you gets new features before releasing production builds

Comment: That's why I am doing this Veli007. QA.

Comment: Eh guess I’m not understanding your English, just keep reading the documentation bro, I’m sure the answer to your problem is there